# Integrating ETL with Java using intellij

Tags: java, etl

I want to start with ETL on java. I am using Intellij. I wanted to know how the integration can be done or which tool is compatible with intellij.
Also if there is any tutorials on the basics of ETL with java.

Exactly what and all I will need if I want to do the transformation of data
It can be basic like just taking in random input from a file and transforming 
the data based on particular logic

Comment: Best place to check for integration is usually an official documentation of one or both integrating parties.

Answer (score 0):

Creating code to extract (query different sources like DB, XML, web service, etc) to transform (you know make everything compatible, removing dup's, creating Dims and Facts) to load them to targets (databases and more)...
 All this is not new. Java is great but creating ETLs with it is creating a non-standar app... And is going to become a legacy and then you need to build a scheduler to run the loads and to integrate with several components.

So. I strongly recommend instead of create a Java app, take a look to products like Informatica PowerCenter and/or Oracle Data Integrator.

This solutions are business wide standard for ETL worldwide, provides objects and methods to avoid apps that needs to be hardly mantein and are on top of any applications... Also are used for integration, migration, B2B, BI... Named...

Good luck!

Comment: Apache Nifi or Apache Spark would be two Java option

Answer (score 0):

You would be re- inventing the wheel  if you are trying to create a Java based etl product .
Talend is a java based open source ETL tool which gives the features of an ETL tool and lets one write Java code  to integrate ..

Pentaho is another Java based ETL tool..

Both of them are popular and have good UI...